# To take a full backup and differential backup of all databases

Tags: sql-server, backup

Can anyone help me with a script to take a full or complete backup of all databases once in a week and to take differential backups daily. ?

Comment: The normal way to do this would be a maintenance plan. Is there a reason you can't use that? For example, are you running Express?

Comment: Yes. I am using Express Edition of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe @Les H has already answered and Yes, ola's script should do the work here without any issues.

However as per the [MS Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019698) you can also do something like:

1. Use SQL Server Management Studio Express or Sqlcmd to create the following stored procedure in your master database named `sp_BackupDatabases`. The script to create the SP is available on the link.
2. create a batch file that will execute the above SP, also specifying the location of backup and its mode, that is Full , differential or log.
3. Schedule a job by using Windows Task Scheduler to execute the batch file that you created in step 2

Answer (score 3):

You should look at Ola Hallengren's scripts

https://ola.hallengren.com/

The FAQ has examples on using these scripts with SQL Express.

https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html

Comment: The code Maintenancesolution.sql has many no.of lines of code which depletes the performance and make it slower. Can you give me a much simple solution..?

Comment: What are you basing the performance on? We've had it running across our entire estate for the last year without issue. Why do you think that many lines of code make it slower? You might also want to check out http://minionware.net/#miniontabs|2 for a second option

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use one of many third-party tools? You can set up scheduled backups as you need full backup once a week and differential backups daily.

You can use [SqlBak](https://sqlbak.com) (SAAS model) or [SQLBackupAndFTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/) they both have a free plan. Or you can try something more expensive like [SQL Backup from RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/) or [Idera](https://www.idera.com/).

So test them and chose the best one that you need.